# Array like object, not displaying specific values but showing whole array. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to use the google maps geocoding service. It spits out values as lat and lng in an array. I removed these values and put them in a separate var so I could use them elsewhere in my code.

```
function geoCode(place,num){
var location = place;
axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
  params:{
    address:location,
    key:''
  }
})
.then(function(response){
  hospitalLocations[num]={
    lat:float(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat),
    lng:float(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng),
  };
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

In setup, I recall the var:

```
console.log(typeof hospitalLocations);
console.log(hospitalLocations);
console.log(hospitalLocations[0]);
```

The typeof gives me "object". 
hospitalLocations gives me a full array that I can open and see the values laid out the same way a regular array would be.
But when I check for a specific value it gives me undefined. 
Is there any way to pull out the values within? 
Thanks

Comment: I suggested an edit to add a couple tags to make it easier for the right people to find your question.

Comment: Can you give a reproductible example ? Where is set `hospitalLocation`, where is called `geoCode` ? What's inside `place` and `num`?

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that `hospitalLocations` is an object not an array .. As I can understand from:

```
...
.then(function(response){
  hospitalLocations[num]={
    lat:float(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat),
    lng:float(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng),
  };
})
...
```

So usually if you want to iterate over an object you would use the following way:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(hospitalLocations))
            console.log(value);
```

I hope this would help you, if that what you're looking for.